# What is difference between javascript and python time stamp?

Tags: javascript, python, time

I have this javascript code:

```
(new Date()).getTime()
```

And this python code:

```
time.time()
```

The first one return some thing like **1410072754803** but the python return something like **1410077369.27** i need the python to return same format as javascript does.How can i get that?

PS:if i use

```
time.time() * 1000
```

it return :

```
1.41007799536e+12
```

Comment: Times the python one by 1000 and convert it to an integer.

Comment: The *comments* on the other answer answer your update; `time.time()` is a float value, round it and turn it into an integer: `int(round(time.time() * 1000))`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Are you sure that javascript epoch is always equal to `time.gmtime(0)` in Python -- whatever systems both language are run?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I have no idea.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: then the question is not a duplicate (in theory)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: no, there is not enough detail here. If there are such issues, then a specific question should be asked. Until such time, we can assume they are the same.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: *the* specific detail is **javascript**. It is enough to make it different from a Python-only question e.g., it is likely that javascript may run on a mobile device (GPS time is available), it is less likely for Python.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: if you know of a *specific issue* that requires a detailed answer, feel free to reopen. Until then, I'm leaving this closed. Both Python and JS have been around long enough (and standardised) that if this was an issue then I'd already expect questions about this.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: it is incorrect to close the question as a duplicate if your knowledge is expressed as [*"I have no idea."*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25708317/what-is-difference-between-javascript-and-python-time-stamp?#comment40213400_25708317) I'll reopen to allow *the possibility* for more knowledgeable people to answer the question in the future. Do you know whether `time.time()` counts leap seconds on some systems? (it shouldn't on POSIX but does it?). The difference shouldn't matter in most applications because when it does matter -- people expect brokenness.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: I think your approach, adding another answer to the other question, is far better. I still stand by my dupe vote here, there is just not enough detail here to see this anything but a 'get timestamp in milliseconds' issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One returns milli seconds, while other returns seconds in float.

Python equivalent of javascript timestamp would be.

```
jts = int(time.time()*1000)
```